# Which is the covariate, dependent and fixed factor in GLM

Tags: multiple-regression

I am new to using SPSS and am getting confused when inputting variables. I am looking at how latitude impacts tree diversity, and how they differ between hemispheres, so want to look at the interaction. 
My data is non-normal, and I am using a general linear model. 
So my understanding is that tree diversity is the dependent variable. Would hemisphere (N or S) be the fixed factor or covariate? And then where does latitude come in in the model?

Any guidance would be hugely appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Both hemisphere and latitude are fixed factors here, and tree diversity is your dependent variable.

It sounds like you're running an ANOVA, but a multiple regression might be more appropriate. In this case, add a third factor, which is hemisphere multiplied by latitude: this is the interaction term.